# Update appbar context based on listviewitem clicked

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, winrt-xaml

How do I change the context of the buttons in an app bar, depending on what is clicked on screen?

In my scenario I have various data bound listViews for different objects such as Users/Projects etc, the appbar contains simple add/remove/edit buttons. I would like to be able to perform these tasks depending on what I have clicked on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember, when you write a XAML app, the best design pattern to use is the MVVM pattern because it is so simple. Including your scenario.

First, your `ListView` has a `SelectedItem` property which is updated whenever the user changes their selection. You should bind this to an `INotifyPropertyChanged` property in your view model; let's pretend it is called `Selected` and be sure it is using `Mode=TwoWay` when you setup the binding.

In addition, to `Selected` in your view model, you should also include an `INotifyPropertyChanged` property like `Button1Visibility` and `Button2Visibility` which you will update from inside the `Selected` setter code. The buttons in your `AppBar` should have their visibility bound to the view model's `Button1Visibility` and `Button1Visibility` properties respectively.

Then, as the user makes changes to the selection, the logic you have implemented in your `Selected` setter code will set the `Visibility` properties in your view model appropriately. Then, the buttons in your `AppBar` will appear and hide in accordance. This making sense?

Something like this

```
public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!object.Equals(storage, value))
        {
            storage = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class ViewModel : BindableBase
{
    object _Selected = default(object);
    public object Selected
    {
        get { return _Selected; }
        set
        {
            base.SetProperty(ref _Selected, value);
            if (value == null)
                this.Button1Visibility = this.Button2Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            else
                this.Button1Visibility = this.Button2Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    Visibility _Button1Visibility = default(Visibility);
    public Visibility Button1Visibility { get { return _Button1Visibility; } set { base.SetProperty(ref _Button1Visibility, value); } }

    Visibility _Button2Visibility = default(Visibility);
    public Visibility Button2Visibility { get { return _Button2Visibility; } set { base.SetProperty(ref _Button2Visibility, value); } }
}
```

In the code above, for example, we hide the buttons when nothing is selected.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done this is to put all of the context buttons into the app bar at design time. I then show or hide the proper ones based on what item(s) the user clicks.

Specifically, my application listens to the `SelectionChanged` event, and then sets the `Visibility` property on the appropriate app bar buttons.